# Laravel: How can I assertJson an array

Tags: laravel, testing, phpunit, laravel-7

I am creating a feature test for a `Seminar`. Everything is working great; I am trying to update my feature test to account for the seminar dates.

Each `Seminar` can have one or many dates, so I am saving these values as a json field:

```
// migration:

...

$table->json('dates');

...
```

Here is what my `Seminar` model looks like:

```
// Seminar.php

protected $casts = [
    'dates' => 'array',
];
```

When saving the seminar, I am returning a json resource:

```
if ($seminar->save()) {
    return response()->json(new SeminarResource($seminar), 200);
    ...
```

Using Postman, my `Seminar` looks a like this:

```
...

"capacity": 100,
"dates": [
    "2020-10-15",
    "2020-10-16"
],

...
```

So far so good!

In my test, I am testing that a seminar can be created.

```
$http->assertStatus(201)

->assertJson([
    'type' => 'seminars',
    'id' => (string)$response->id,
    'attributes' => [
        'dates' => $response->attributes->dates, // General error: 25 column index out of range
```

I've tried to convert the array to a string, or `json_encode` the value in the resource. I don't think that's the correct way since I am already casting the value as an array in the model.

How can I assert that my `dates` is returning an array?

```
 +"dates": array:2 [
      0 => "2020-10-15"
      1 => "2020-10-16"
    ]
```

Thank you for your suggestions!

**EDIT**

When I `dd($response->attributes->dates);` this is what I'm getting (which is correct).

```
array:2 [
  0 => "2020-10-15"
  1 => "2020-10-16"
]
```

What I'm not sure is how to assert an array like that. Since I'm using faker to generate the date, I don't really know (or care) what the date is, just want to assert that it is in fact an array.

I've tried something like:

```
 'dates' => ['*'],
```

However, that just adds another element to the array.

**EDIT 2**

If I make the array a string,

```
'dates' => json_encode($response->attributes->dates),
```

I'll get an error like this:

```
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@


-    'dates' => '["2020-10-15","2020-10-16"]',
+    'dates' => 
+    array (
+      0 => '2020-10-15',
+      1 => '2020-10-16',
+    ),
```

In my database, the values are stored like this:

```
["2020-10-15","2020-10-16"]
```

My actual test looks like this:

```
$http->assertStatus(201)
            ->assertJsonStructure([
                'type', 'id', 'attributes' => [
                    'name', 'venue', 'dates', 'description', 'created_at', 'updated_at',
                ],
            ])
            ->assertJson([
                'type' => 'workshops',
                'id' => (string)$response->id,
                'attributes' => [
                    'name' => $response->attributes->name,
                    'venue' => $response->attributes->venue,             
                    'dates' => $response->attributes->dates,
                    'description' => $response->attributes->description,
                    'created_at' => (string)$response->attributes->created_at,
                    'updated_at' => (string)$response->attributes->updated_at,
                ],
            ]);

        $this->assertDatabaseHas('workshops', [
            'id' => $response->id,
            'name' => $response->attributes->name,
            'venue' => $response->attributes->venue,
            'dates' => $response->attributes->dates,
            'description' => $response->attributes->description,
        ]);
```

Comment: Did you tried with: `$response->getOriginalContent()->attributes->dates`?

Comment: did you check what is the format inside `$response->attributes->dates` with a dd() ?

Comment: @N69S - yes. It is an array. I'm just not sure how to write the test to accept that it is an array. I've updated my question to show the exact output.

Comment: did you try phpunit's assertIsArray() method?

Comment: if you need to assert it as an array, assert it as such on its own. Still dont see the full picture of your issue right now. wher is the "capacity": 100, in the json response in the assertion ?